# Width issue - Kendo UI For Angular 2 - Combobox

Tags: combobox, width, angular-ui-bootstrap, kendo-ui-angular2

Issue with the width of Kendo UI for Angualar 2 - Combobox.
The width doesn't match with the control's width when style is specified.

Please take a look on the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VClWnCUkxUyuxMn3vW5U)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `

    <input id="ac" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="allowCustom">
    <label for="ac">Allow custom values</label>
    <br/>
    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
    <kendo-combobox [data]="listItems" [allowCustom]="allowCustom" style="width:100%">
    </kendo-combobox>
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
       <label for="ac">Allow custom values</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
    public allowCustom: boolean = true;
    public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue should be fixed with version - 0.18.1. Run `npm update` and see if it works.